# How to add calculated column to PowerBI datasets

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a dataset in Power BI web, and then imported it on Power BI desktop (using File -> Get data -> Power BI datasets).

I don't see a way of adding Calculated Columns. Does the dataset need some special configuration to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience you won't be able to see the columns because it using direct query. you can still add some columns and measure but your'e basically flying blind. you can just select the table in the report(visual view) and add column however you'll have to play the guessing game. But if you know your dataset you should be fine.

However a Dataflow wouldn't give the issue you're having.

Comment: Thanks, Dataflow is the way to go.